# Chamilo - Search bar into footer

Tags: search, footer, chamilo-lms

I have a problem with `Chamilo 1.9.8`. I want to add Google Search bar to a website into the footer, but I don't know which file I have to edit to insert the code, and where that file is situated.

I have never worked with this system, so I am new in this category, please can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

If it's just a matter of updating the footer, you can find it in 1.9.8 in main/template/default/layout/footer.tpl

Note that, for these changes to take effect, you'll have to delete the template caching in archive/twig/ (just delete the *contents* of that folder) or click the "Archive directory cleanup" link on your Chamilo administration panel.

You can also find useful tips about modifying the templates in the (unfinished) developers documentation here: https://github.com/chamilo/docs/tree/master/1.9/en/developer.

Note that:

- you should update to 1.9.10.2 to avoid security flaws
- 1.9.10 has a way for you to create a copy of the "default" template and configure it in your configuration file (search main/install/configuration.dist.php for $_configuration['default_template']